# Setting value of dropdownlist which a data source parameter is bound to

Tags: asp.net

I have some drop down lists on a page which get their SelectedValue from a session variable. This allows the value of the dropdowns to be saved across multiple pages.

Problem is the dropdown selected value is being used as a parameter to a separate data source on the page.

If I try to set the dropdown list's value before the dropdown list is databound, I get an exception because the dropdown list has not been populated yet.
If I try to set the dropdown list's value too late, the other data source will be executed with the original value of the dropdown list instead of it's current.

Is there a proper order to handle these events in?

Comment: you can send session variable in parameter.

Comment: Try populating dropdownlist in `PreInit` or `OnInit`; and set dropdown selected value in appropriate method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do binding on the data source until it has had time to get the value from the dropdown. Add an event handler to the dropdown's [`DataBound`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.basedataboundcontrol.databound.aspx) event. In that event handler you can bind on the data source, using the selected value of the dropdown.